# Vtiger custom link with $current_user variable

Tags: php, vtiger

I am trying to add a custom link to a custom page using the vtiger_link table, with 2 parameters; 1 is the trouble ticket id which works fine:

This is in the URL field in the database:

```
modules/Helpdesk%20Info/index.php?ticketid=$RECORD$"target='helpdeskinfo'
```

and 2 is the id of the logged in user ($current_user) but it doesn't work:

```
modules/Helpdesk%20Info/index.php?ticketid=$RECORD$&$user=$current_user"target='helpdeskinfo'
```

It shows the page just as it should, but the variable $user gets the value '$current_user':

```
http://localhost:8888/modules/Helpdesk%20Info/index.php?ticketid=135409&$user=$current_user
```

I wanted to post a picture of the table, but I don't have enough reputation for that.

I have tried many things, but I am clearly doing something wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think it's a problem of PHP string quotes. These don't seem correct to me honestly.

Comment: i know, i have tried both single and double quotes, with and without slashes, it doesn't work.. i am new to both Vtiger and PHP so i might be missing something obvious.

Comment: then i say that the problem is in the dollar signs, that aren't doing what you expect: notice `$RECORD$` has two dollar signs.

Comment: if i use the $record$ alone, it works fine, its the other variable that's not working. when i drop the last dollar sign it doesn't work either..

Comment: that's because the dollar sign in that line isn't a variable identifier, but it's something else, i guess.

Comment: that's right,it's the current record id. it works on close to every tab, in this case it's trouble tickets, but i have seen it work in accounts as well. just like $MODULE$ returns the current module..

Comment: i have heard about something called "smarty" it appears i need to use that, do you happen to know what it is? thank you for your time.

Comment: Smarty is a PHP template engine, it's awesome (imho) but i don't think it's related.

Comment: it's because i need to get the variable first, before i can send it to my page trough the url.. somehow i didn't have it already. is global $current_user; not enough to retrieve it?

Comment: Smarty won't help you in that regard i guess.

Comment: then i am not sure how i am supposed to do it.. thank you for your help though.

Comment: got it! $current_user = $_REQUEST[ck_login_id_vtiger]; did the job.. its amazing how i was messing with this for almost a week, and it comes down to one line of code :) thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: since you found a solution, feel free to write is an answer to your question, for future reference. This is allowed by the community, it's even encouraged, so please do it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not need to put the variable in the URL,

the reason I could not use the `$current_user` variable is because it didn't exist in `"detailview.php"` which is where the link ends up.

I used:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($GLOBALS);
echo "</pre>";
```

to view all globals, there I found the  `authenticated_user_id`

Knowing I could use this I was able to access the global from my file without the URL:

`$current_user = $_SESSION["authenticated_user_id"];`

I would like to thank `STT LCU` for his advice, as he was the only one who helped me through this problem, which took me a full week in total.

Comment: This is not actually what I was looking for but it is a nice surprise of information that I immediately thought of a way to use it so thank you for this. Have an upvote.